# Go through dynamic list in Angular

Tags: angular, list, foreach

I have a problem in my Angular 4 app.

Here is my problem: 
I have a model like this:

```
export interface Vehicles {
  vehicleID: string;
  vehicleName: string;
  selected: boolean;
}
```

So, in my component I got this:

```
selectedVehicles: Array<Vehicles>;
listOfselectedVehicles: string[];
```

so I need all the `vehicleID` of my `selectedVehicles` inside my `listOfselectedVehicles`

something like this (but this doesn't work)

```
for (var _i = 0; _i < this.selectedVehicles.length; _i++) {
    this.listOfselectedVehicles[_i] = this.selectedVehicles[_i].vehicleID;
}
```

Comment: what is the error.?

Comment: @FranklinPious in console I got this "TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
selectedVehicles: Array<Vehicles> = [];
listOfselectedVehicles: string[] = [];

// -.....- here put code which will fill selectedVehicles array

this.selectedVehicles.forEach(vec => {
  this.listOfselectedVehicles.push(vec.vehicleID);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

initialise as `listOfselectedVehicles: string[] = []`;